# Is the Noahide Law actually composed of the seven codified macro-obligations or does it de facto include other precepts?

Tags: halacha, noachide-laws

I'm an Italian Noahide.

My question may seem abstruse; I try to explain myself better.

The Noahide Law is notoriously codified in seven macro-obligations, in turn specified in more detailed precepts; however, the Halakhah includes further prohibitions concerning the Gentiles, prohibitions that are not specifically included in the Noachide Law.

I quote for example:

-The observance of the Shabbat is forbidden to a Gentile (see Talmud Bavli Sanhredrin 58b)

-The marriage between a Jew and a Gentile is forbidden, as is any sexual intercourse between them (see Mishneh Torah-Issurei Biah 12:1)

But then, on the basis of the principle "nullum crimen, nulla poena sine lege", why should the Noahide Law also not encompass precepts such as those mentioned above?

If a particular halakhah prohibits the Gentiles from having a specific conduct, I believe that it is binding on the Gentiles themselves, and that therefore they should be informed of the existence of such rules, so that the Gentiles are put in a position not to infringe this type of prescription.

Comment: Have you read the books of rabbi Eliahu Ben Amosegh from Livorno?

Comment: Welcome back! Great to see you again, it's been a while.

Comment: @kouty Yes sure! Rav Benamozegh was a great master of Italian and European Judaism of the nineteenth century vulgar era

Comment: @DonielF thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

They actually established a Noahide court system about a decade ago in order to deal with the issue you've brought up.

Noahidism is a complicated topic because it only really gets discussed in generalities by the Rabbis. Most Rabbis aren't typically dealing with Noahides and Noahide issues so they only speak in basic terms when discussing the topic. There are, however, Rabbis who specialize in the topic and a body of these Rabbis exist throughout the world.

Much like Jewish law, there needs to be a more detailed breakdown of the laws so that individuals can deal with whatever situations come up and best observe the laws. You are 100% correct in this statement.

The Sanhedrin as it once existed no longer exists. That being said, a version of the body which claims to be attempting to reestablish the Sanhedrin exists in Israel. **This group established something called the Jerusalem Court for Issues of Bnei Noah.**

They deal with issues which impact the "Halacha" of B'nei Noah in the way a Rabbinical authority deals with issues of Jewish law.

The Jewish community has reached a point now where groups have been established to help guide Noahides towards best possible observance. Different groups exist so I'll link you to some resources as this question may be more easily answered by Rabbis who work directly with the noahide community. Many exist worldwide, including Europe, which may be of use to you. I'll link to that below.

[**Noahide Study Resources**](https://asknoah.org/courses) (You may have already found these but just in case)

[**Worldwide Noahide Contacts**](https://asknoah.org/worldwide-contacts)

**Rome, Italy specifically cites Rabbi Shalom D. Hazan as their contact.** He's actually affiliated with Chabad Lubavitch of Italy so his professional contact info can be found through the Chabad website. I'll list this below for you.

[**Chabad Lubavitch di Monteverde - Rabbi Shalom Hazan**](https://www.chabad.org/centers/default_cdo/aid/117863/jewish/Chabad-Lubavitch-di-Monteverde.htm)

I'm not sure what part of Italy you reside in but he may be your best bet if you're seeking specific answers to your questions.